# SVG not rendered properly on IE and Edge as browser size changes

Tags: html, css, image, svg

I have an SVG that has lines distributed evenly (a black box with 4 thick white lines).

On IE and Edge, if the browser size changes, the width of these lines changes and it looks more like a barcode instead of a box with evenly separated lines.

Works fine on all other browsers.

Does anyone know how I could fix this?

Comment: Sounds like a very specific use case that I wouldn't worry about. IE alone has a small user base coupled with the fact you need to resize to reproduce. IMO it's more effort to fix than what is worth.

Comment: Please show us the code of the SVG.